# xtify reactor onBeforeMessage is not working

Tags: reactor, xtify

I am using reactor http://getreactor.xtify.com/ on a backbone application and trying to build a custom inbox box. I use auto-run="false" config param. Then I define a function for the onBeforeMessage

```
Reactor.onBeforeMessage(function(message){
console.log('new Message');
});
```

This function most of the times is been called but some other not.
First question why does the onBeforeMessage is triggered although I specify auto-run="false" ?
Second question why does the onBeforeMessage is not always triggered ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use:

```
data-auto-run="false"
```

instead of:

```
auto-run="false"
```

The 'data-' prefix is [the HTML5 way](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to store metadata on an HTML element.

You can see a JS Fiddle with some in-depth explanation of how to implement a custom inbox here:

http://goo.gl/8Ej9vM

Note that the function that you register with Reactor.onBeforeMessage() accepts a list of the messages that have been triggered rather than a single message. You can see more documentation here:

http://getreactor.xtify.com/documentation/notifications.php